# Find specific duplicated letters or numbers in rows

Tags: excel, duplicates

I'm trying to find specific cells in row that have duplicated letter, I need to find any cell that have duplicated letter or number except letter 's'

Example:

```
**Ks Kd 7s**   *<- this one has two letters "K" so I want it to be selected*  
**As 9d 9c**   *<- this one has two numbers "9" so I want it to be selected*  
**As 9S 8c**   *<- this one only has two letters "s", so it should not be selected*
```

I want to set background color for selected rows. I thought I should use filters to do it, but there are to many cases and Excel only allows me to use only 2 filters at time.

Thanks

EDIT: after few comments, I saw that format is always same and I always have letters in same position, so we want to find out if letters on position X have duplicates if this is format of every cell: 
Xy Xy Xy

Comment: Are the items always two characters? And does position matter, ie would `Ks dK 7s` be selected?

Comment: characters are always on same place, they represent boards in poker, (for someone that plays poker, it's going to be easier to understand), so we want to find out if we have duplicated values 'X' if this is the format: Xy Xy Xy

Comment: **unclear**  Are the duplicates within a single cell or across cells in some row  ??

Comment: duplicates are always in single cell

Comment: If you want to count the number of occurrences of a string within a string, you would do something like `=(Len(A1)-Substitute(A1,"stringToReplace",""))/countOfCharactersInSubstituteString`, e.g., A1 = "cat cat cat"... `=(len(A1)-substitute(a1,"c",""))/1` is 3, so 3 occurrences, whereas `=(len(A1)-substitute(a1,"cat",""))/3` is 3

Comment: So is it possible for letter s to be in the X position so that you would still ignore it, like Sa sb de  would not count?

Comment: @TomSharpe you can use `Find`, `Left`, `Right`, and/or `Mid`, to only substitute from a portion of the string.

Comment: Yes but it could be any character (apart from s) that's repeated, it seems quite tricky to me - job for mid + frequency (as @scott may demonstrate to us shortly!) So far I have got a formula that looks for any repeated characters anywhere, but not just in the X positions.

Comment: @TomSharpe no, it can't be, so I just need to find out if letters on positions 1 3 and 9 are duplicated or not, letter I figure out that "s" can only be on position "y"

Comment: @TomSharpe for this particular case you can use `Mid(A1,1,1)`, `Mid(A1,3,1)`, & `Mid(A1,5,1)`, with substitutes... I believe you would want a set of helper columns to account for the numbers, letters... I am curious how "10" is being handled, as that card exists, and increases the character count of the total string, assuming `9S` could be `10S`.

Comment: OK well that case wasn't in the question and reveals my ignorance of poker! Obviously could get round it with if statements but it would be messy - or probably just substitute '10' -> 'T'.

Comment: as @TomSharpe guessed, 10 is labeled as T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hi-light any cells with duplicate letters.  Just select and cells you wish to examine and run:

```
Sub ColorDups()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        If dupcheck(r.Value) Then r.Interior.ColorIndex = 27
    Next r
End Sub


Public Function dupcheck(s As String) As Boolean
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, CH As String
    dupcheck = False
    L = Len(s)
    If L < 2 Then Exit Function
    For i = 1 To L - 1
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[A-Z,a-z]" And CH <> "s" Then
            For j = i + 1 To L
                If CH = Mid(s, j, 1) Then
                    dupcheck = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To test for numbers as well as letters, replace:

```
If CH Like "[A-Z,a-z]" And CH <> "s" Then
```

with:

```
If CH Like "[A-Z,a-z,0-9]" And CH <> "s" Then
```

Comment: This one looks to be working, but only with letters, if I have 2 numbers, it doesn't work, for example: 9s 8d 8c should be highlighted as well

Comment: @GoranB  Sorry, will fix

Comment: @GoranB  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting comment formula as an answer, with the assumption that you are dealing with data in a single cell (1 string).

---

If you want to count the number of occurrences of a string within a string, you would do something like:

```
=(Len(A1)-Len(Substitute(A1,"stringToReplace","")))/countOfCharactersInSubstituteString
```

Example:

```
A1 = "cat cat cat"
```

We want to know how many "c" are in this string so we use:

```
stringToReplace = "c"
countOfCharactersInSubstituteString = 1
(len(A1)-len(substitute(a1,"c","")))/1
```

The answer is 3, so 3 occurrences.

---

If we want to know the occurrence count of "cat", we would use:

```
stringToReplace = "cat"
countOfCharactersInSubstituteString = 3
(len(A1)-len(substitute(a1,"cat","")))/3
```

Where the answer is 3 occurrences.

---

Note the use of the normalizing factor of `countOfCharactersInSubstituteString` so that you don't see that 9 characters were removed, but 3 occurrences of that string.

---

**Edit**

Just realized I forgot the `len()` around the substitute... fixed.

---

**Edit2**

I utilized some helper items for this:
[image]
Formula from B11:  `=(LEN($A11)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A11,B$10,"")))/LEN(B$10)`

You could use `If(#occurrences>1,"!","")` to make it easier to see, but this would allow you to pretty easily check items out for your list of card combinations.

Using this formula in B11:  `=IF((LEN($A11)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A11,B$10,"")))/LEN(B$10)>1,"X","")`
[image]

Comment: your logic sounds good to me, but I keep getting this error "There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula?..."

Comment: I'm still getting same error, not only from you but from other solutions as well, as far as I can see, problem is that I have decimal separators set up differently, so I have to use ; instead of , in formula or something like that, I'm trying to figure out what exactly I need to fix in formula in order for it to work

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is in threes and we only care about the first caracter:

```
=IF(OR(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,{1,4,7},1),""))>1),"Select","Not Select")
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

OR

```
=IF(ISERROR(MODE.SNGL(MATCH(MID(A1,{1,4,7},1),MID(A1,{1,4,7},1),0))),"Not Select","Select")
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the length and format is always the same, try

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(MATCH(MID(A2,{1,4,7},1),MID(A2,{1,4,7},1),0),MATCH(MID(A2,{1,4,7},1),MID(A2,{1,4,7},1),0)))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

or is this over-elaborate?

Comment: Something with my format of excel is not accepting this type of formulas, so I've used VBA as Gary suggested, but thanks for the help and time, it's appreciated @Tom